# RStudio Server doesn't work from one laptop, but work from another

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

We are working with RStudio-server using web browser on two laptops.
When working from one laptop - application doesn't start: I see only empty and inactive interface windows. When working from another laptop - everything ok.
However, the problem occurs for only one account.

Cash cleanse and reboot of rstudio-server didn't help.

```
systemctl stop rstudio-server
killall -9 rstudio
systemctl restart rstudio-server
```

I suppose that RStudio-Server create local directory with settings on local pc.
And on one of laptops this settings directory was mishandled.

Could you please help to resolve this problem.

RStudio Server version:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better handled at RStudio's dedicated support site.

Comment: if another user not facing any issue like you then try to delete that user and create a new user & update your browser

Answer (score 0):

create new users and update your browser or try in a different browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps!